# If - Strange Behavior in Detecting Type

Tags: vb.net, casting

I discovered this strange behavior in VB.Net today in trying to work with nullable DateTime data.  I am pulling a DateTime value out of an XML file for inserting into a database, and I want to allow for an empty value.  So I thought I should use `If` to prevent casting errors:

```
Dim LastRun As DateTime? = _
    If(rowData("LastRun") = "", Nothing, CType(rowData("LastRun"), DateTime))
```

It seems like this should return a value of `Nothing` in the case that the `If` is false, or a value of the date time from `LastRun` if the value is not blank.  Instead, when the `If` condition returns false, I get a value of `DateTime.MinValue`, which causes an exception on insert to the database due to SQL DateTime underflow.

I was able to fix it by using `DateTime?` as the cast in the last parameter, but this behavior seems odd to me.  The expected type is clearly `DateTime?` because that's the variable type.  Also, the narrowest type that can allow for both possible result values is `DateTime?`, since it could be either a `DateTime` or `Nothing`.  And yet somehow it decides that the result value should be `DateTime` and then I guess typecasts `Nothing` to `DateTime.MinValue`?  What is going on here?

Part of the problem is I'm used to C#, and the equivalent expression `rowData["LastRun"] == "" ? null : (DateTime)rowData["LastRun"])` doesn't even compile (as expected), because there's "no implicit conversion between `DateTime` and `null`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nothing` is not the same as `null` in C#, it is a mixture between `null` and `default(T)`. So when you use `Nothing` on a value type(like the structure `DateTime`) you get it's default value what is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense.  Is there even a `C#` equivalent to `Nothing`?

Comment: Yes, what i've mentioned `default(T)`, so if you use `default(DateTime)` you get `DateTime.MinValue`. However, there is nothing in C# that contains both, `null` + `default(T)` as `Nothing` in VB.NET.

Comment: OK, now this is really weird.  `If(IsDBNull(rowData("LastRun")) OrElse rowData("LastRun") = "", CType(Nothing, DateTime?), CType(rowData("LastRun"), DateTime?))` - this expression returns a value of type `String`... o.O?